# For addHead method why check if tail == null?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I'm taking a Java data structures course and currently studying singly linked list.  In the method for addHead, why do we need to check if the tail == null?  And when true, why is tail = head?

```
public void addHead(T d){
  Node<T> n = new Node<>(d, head);
  head = n;
  size++
  if(tail == null)
   tail = head;
}
```

Full code here: https://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~ryba/cs313/linkedList/LinkedList.java

Comment: You need to show more code so we can see how `tail` is used. From the sound of it, the list also stores a pointer to its last element (which only if it was previously empty has now changed)

Comment: Hey @Thilo I've inserted the link to the code I'm studying, thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: `tail` should always point to the last item in the list when the list is not empty, right?  So how do you make that happen when you've just inserted the very first item into the list?  And how do you figure out that the node you're inserting is, in fact, the very first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `head` is a reference to the first node in the list.

In `tail` is a reference to the last node in the list.

(The `tail` reference is used to allow adding elements to the end of the list in constant time.)

A empty list has `head == null` and `tail == null`.

A list with one element has `head == tail`, `head != null` and `tail != null`.

Lists with more than one element have `head != tail`, `head != null` and `tail != null`.

`addHead` creates a new Node `n` for the new element `d`, with a reference to the next node in the list that is stored in `head` (which is null for the first element). The `head` is assigned the reference to that newly created node `n`.

The `if(tail == null)` is true, when adding the first element to the list. The reference to `n` was already saved in `head` and also needs to be saved in `tail` with `tail = head;` (also possible: `tail = n;`) to fulfill the `head == tail` condition.

When adding additional elements to the `head` of the list (`addHead`), then `tail` isn't changed, but should continue to point to the last node of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your list implementation also allows appending to the end.

To make this work efficiently, the list maintains a `tail` pointer to its last element. It is possible to do it without that pointer, but then you'd need to go through the whole list to find the last element everytime, making appending O(N) instead of O(1). For the same reason, your implementation also has a `size` counter.

When you add a new element to a previously empty list that `tail` pointer needs to be adjusted to point at the newly created single node.

Note that when adding to the front of the list, you only have to adjust the `tail` when the list was empty before. In all other cases, the `tail` stays where it was, and only the `head` and `size` change.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, helped clear out my confusion.